# React Native End to End Tests with Detox: Getting height, width, and other properties of matched elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, testing, automation, detox

As the title states, I would like to programmatically retrieve properties of matched elements in Detox. I *know* Detox sees them, because as we all infamously know when a `toBeVisible` expectation fails by the 75% view rule (a built in Detox opinion for the uninitated), we can see what detox 'got', usually it is a message something like this:

```
Got: "ReactTextView{id=13725, visibility=VISIBLE, width=376, height=102, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams@ac227fb, tag=PROFILE_NAME_TEXT, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=486.0, y=120.0, text=Anonymous, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"
```

So we have things like the `width`, `height`, `focus` and so on.

My question is, how can we get at these properties programmatically? Specifically, I have an element that is expanding after a button tap and I want to be sure the height is larger than it was before.

If you check the methods available for `element(by.id("SOME_ID"))`, there are only action methods available...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally discovered the answer which was hard to find initial due to missing typings of `detox` at the time. Properties like `height` and `width` that I mentioned are available through `getAttributes()` method:

```
const attributes = await element(by.text('Tap Me')).getAttributes();
expect(attributes.text).toBe('Tap Me');

const multipleMatchedElements = await element(by.text('Multiple')).getAttributes();
expect(multipleMatchedElements.elements.length).toBe(5);
expect(multipleMatchedElements.elements[0].identifier).toBe('FirstElement');
```

The available properties vary between Android and iOS as well. See [the documentation](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/APIRef.ActionsOnElement.md#getAttributes) in the library for `getAttributes()`, and [the pull request on detox](https://github.com/wix/Detox/pull/3009) which adds all the types.